# Jquery Lazy Loading not working properly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement a jQuery technique called lazy loading . The goal I'm trying to achieve is  I want the page to load without waiting for all the images request so , I want the page to load first with CSS, etc., and let the images load slowly.

The issue I'm facing here is, it waits for all the image requests before the page is loaded which is the opposite of the concept of lazy loading. Can someone help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/float.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $(function(){
                        $("img.lazy").lazyload();
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </head>
<img class="lazy" src="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/grey.jpg" data-orig="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/beach.jpg?w=300&h=187" width="400" height ="400"/>
<br>
<img class="lazy" src="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/grey.jpg" data-orig="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8349/8225268620_4e00a8f603_m.jpg" width="400" height ="400"/>
<br>
<img class="lazy" src="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/grey.jpg" data-orig="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8338/8224516167_bc7a5f6699_m.jpg" width="400" height ="400"/>
<br>
<img class="lazy" src="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/grey.jpg" data-orig="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8199/8219175940_effa3f66ca_m.jpg" width="400" height ="400"/>
<br>
<img class="lazy" src="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/grey.jpg" data-orig="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8490/8215600456_de252d155d_m.jpg" width="400" height ="400"/>
<br>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not using the plugin properly. Read the [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), you're supposed to put the URL of the image in the `data-original` attribute. The `src` attribute should contain the URL of a dummy image that's used for all the items until they load the real image.

```
<img class="lazy" src="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/grey.jpg" data-orig="http://wannabeyummymummie.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/beach.jpg?w=300&h=187" width="400" height ="400"/>
```

Also, as the other answers pointed out, you need to call the plugin from the document ready handler.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload(
        { data_attribute: "orig" 
        });
});
```

The `data_attribute` option tells the plugin what `data-XXX` attribute to find the real URL in. It defaults to `data-original`, the above option changes it to `data-orig` to match the mistaken HTML I gave you.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sbrgb/3/)

Comment: You have the same URL in `src` and `data-original`, don't you? That's wrong.

Comment: All the images should point to the same `src`, which should be a simple image that's used as a placeholder. This allows them to load quickly, because it's cached the first time.

Comment: okay , i replaced all . Can you just take a look at the modified code above . The problem now is , It doesn't load anything at all just that dummy image

Comment: Try downloading the plugin and loading it from there. I got an error when I tried accessing it from github in a fiddle.

Comment: See the change I posted above. Either add the option to the `lazyload` call, or change all your images to use `data-original` instead of `data-orig`.

Comment: You should also use a real image file for the `src` attribute, not a broken image.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your script in the onload function so that it does not execute until the page is loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your script under document.ready. SO that your `$("img.lazy")` is executed after the document is loaded and just when the image tags are available in DOM.

```
$(function(){
   $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

easiest way you can find this out is place an alert or console.log just before `$("img.lazy").lazyload();` i.e

```
<script>
console.log($("img.lazy").length); // this will log 0
 $("img.lazy").lazyload();
 </script>
```

Comment: PSL do you mean like this <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
 
 $(function(){
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
 })
       });

  </script>